# How to implement openVPN in iOS?

Tags: ios, vpn, openvpn

Is there any library for implementing openVPN in iOS? I have to implement the functionality like openVPN app for ios. I search a lot but there is no solution. Most of the post are out dated. I got some example from the github but they are also not so useful[Most of the files are missing]. I want add/delete vpn from my app. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple doesn't support changing VPN or add form app (except app from [openVpn](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/openvpn-connect/id590379981?mt=8)).

But what you can do is show the *open in* menu for the .ovpn file, open the file in openVpn app, and then user can add/delete/start/stop VPN from there.

Comment: does there any documentation for it that apple doesn't allow it ?

Comment: Hi, Currently i don't have the link, but for iOS 8 you can check this link : http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/ i think it is possible for iOS 8(I haven't tried it)

Comment: @souvickcse do have any code samples/demo example for it ?

Comment: Yes old days :D